# "outOfMemoryError java heap space" calculating histogram, trade of RAM vs Time?

Tags: java, performance, swing, out-of-memory, histogram

I've been working with my project for a while which at some points calculates the Histogram of a big image (Working with photos of up to 40Mpx, but in general around 10-20Mpx.

I was always using a laptop with 16GB of RAM and I had not noticed any problem. Today I switched to a 6GB ram laptop and with photos of 17Mpx this Exception started to appear when I was calculating an Histogram.

I had switched to this way of calculating it because It was faster than iterating over all pixels and getting all the colors in each pixel.

What is your advice on how should I write such a code?

If I'm looking to make the program faster I think I need to use more RAM (this big double[] object). If the PC has enough RAM there won't be any problem and the program will run smooth, but if the PC doesn't have this much RAM it will just crash and make the program useless.

So should I write the code in a "slower way" by iterating over all pixels by hand and make it "safer"?

Or am I doing something wrong and both things can be done at the same time?

This is the piece of code were this outOfMemoryError occurs:

```
// dataset
    dataset = new HistogramDataset();
    final int w = image.getWidth();
    final int h = image.getHeight();
    double[] r = new double[w * h]; //Here some PC's with not enough RAM will crash
    double[] s = new double[w * h];
    double[] t;
    r = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, r);
    s = r;
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.red"), r, BINS);
    r = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 1, r);
    t = new double[r.length + s.length]; //Add R+G
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, t, 0, s.length);
    System.arraycopy(r, 0, t, s.length, r.length);
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.green"), r, BINS);
    r = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 2, r);
    s = new double[r.length + t.length]; //Add R+G+B
    System.arraycopy(t, 0, s, 0, t.length);
    System.arraycopy(r, 0, s, t.length, r.length);
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.blue"), r, BINS);
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.brigthness"), s, BINS);

    // chart
    chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.histogram"), "",
            "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
```

**Update**: 
Using the option -Xmx suggested in the comments solves the problem.

Results using @TheConstructor optimization, in a virtual machine using windows 10 32bits and 3,5GB ram:

- Before the optimization with less than -Xmx1444m will run the exception
- After the optimization with less than -Xmx824m will run the exception

This is what I have by default:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr HeapSize
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 67108864                            {product}
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 16777216                            {product}
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 268435456                           {product}
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Which is around 268MB, and the maximum I can set by the command in this computer is 1,5GB. I find it strange  that without anything else opened the whole windows with any other program requires 2GB of the 3.5GB.

Comment: A quick answer is: increase the memory used by your program, however it doesn't resolve your algorithm optimization. For running this you could try: -Xms1024m (you must check how much RAM your JDK allows, genrally it depends on the server or client version) followed by -XX:MaxPermSize=128m. Here you are an explanation of the params: https://blog4jose.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/memory-permgen-classloader/

Comment: Did you specify the `-Xmx` JVM option? If not, try that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately I guess that you will need to specify a correctly sized `-Xmx` or `-XX:MaxHeapSize` argument to your `java`-call. The defaults are derived from available memory and limit the amount of memory Java can use. Try to figure out a working size. You could try e.g. `-Xmx2g`. Some details on `-Xmx` [can be found inside documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Looking at your code you can eliminate `t` and skip initialization of `s`. Though I guess it will not solve all issues here are my modifications:

```
    // dataset
    dataset = new HistogramDataset();
    final int w = image.getWidth();
    final int h = image.getHeight();
    double[] buffer = new double[w * h];
    double[] rgb;

    buffer = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, buffer);
    rgb = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length * 3); // copy as otherwise it gets overwritten in next getSamples
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.red"), buffer, BINS);

    buffer = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 1, buffer);
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, rgb, buffer.length, buffer.length); //Add G
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.green"), buffer, BINS);

    buffer = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 2, buffer);
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, rgb, buffer.length * 2, buffer.length); //Add B
    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.blue"), buffer, BINS);

    dataset.addSeries(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.brigthness"), rgb, BINS);

    // chart
    chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram(lang.getString("HistogramRGB.String.histogram"), "", "", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
```

Depending on whether or not `addSeries` creates a copy of the supplied data, you will probably need to assign `buffer` a new array before each call to `getSamples`. If I correctly guessed it is [Raster#getSamples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#getSamples-int-int-int-int-int-double:A-) you could also use `(double[]) null` as argument instead of `buffer` and let `getSamples` allocate the array for you.

If precision doesn't matter too much you could also switch `double[]` with `float[]` which saves half of the memory.

Comment: [`getSamples ()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/statistics/HistogramDataset.html#line.134) copies the data, so a pre-allocated array can be safely recycled; a complete example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513).

Comment: @trashgod so if `addSeries` copies the data, the remaining question could be whether or not concatinating the RGB-values yields the right result or if the values should be added and then devided by 3.

Comment: Depending on the definition of [_brightness_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/596216/230513).

Comment: Thank you, your answer was really useful as I've written in the update of the question. @trashgod I'm not sure if brightness is the correct word in English, but I want my Histogram to have an empirical measure (radiometry) not related to the human eye (photometry) so I think it should be correct as it is.

Comment: @nck glad I could help. If it solves your problem, everything is ok. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 3):

If possible it is better to reduce the objects creation  so that heap space memory will be reduced. If all the objects are mandatory in your application, then use command line arguments while running your application:

```
java -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size 

(OR)

java -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

Comment: I think it is often both. I tried my best to optimize the snippet allocation-wise in my answer.