# Overlapping of Multiple IntervalBarRenderer

Tags: jfreechart

[This example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDualAxisDemo5.htm) demonstrates how to avoid overlapping multiple bars on dual axis by adding null series at each data set. By following the example I have created four DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset objects, each on its own separate axis (the complete code is given below).

The advantage of adding null series at each data set is visible in the following figure e.g. Series 2 is kept apart from Series 1.

[image]

But still, Series 3 is overlapped by Series 4 and that is why Series 3 is hidden (by Series 4). I could not find the reason and get the solution.

How to avoid this ovelapping, also is there any other alternative technique to demonstrate multiple category problem (having intervals as in my problem) in a more efficient and convenient way?

```
public class IntervalBarChartTest extends ApplicationFrame {
    public IntervalBarChartTest(String title) {
        super(title);
        JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }
    private static DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset createDataset1() {

        Number[] series1_Start = new Number[] {25,50};
        Number[] series1_End = new Number[] {50,75};
        Number[] dymmy1_Start = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] dummy1_End = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[][] starts = new Number[][]{series1_Start,dymmy1_Start};
        Number[][] ends = new Number[][] {series1_End,dummy1_End};
        String[]  categoryKeys = {"50th%ile", "90th%ile"};
        String[] seriesKeys = {"Series1",""};
        DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset dataset= new DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset(seriesKeys,categoryKeys,starts, ends);
        return dataset;
    }
    private static DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset createDataset2() {
        Number[] dymmy1_Start = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] dummy1_End = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] series2_Start = new Number[] {150,150};
        Number[] series2_End = new Number[] {200,200};
        Number[] dymmy3_Start = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] dummy3_End = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[][] starts = new Number[][]{dymmy1_Start,series2_Start,dymmy3_Start};
        Number[][] ends = new Number[][] {dummy1_End,series2_End, dummy3_End};
        String[]  categoryKeys = {"50th%ile", "90th%ile"};
        String[] seriesKeys = {"","Series2",""};
        DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset dataset= new DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset(starts, ends);
        dataset.setSeriesKeys(seriesKeys);
        dataset.setCategoryKeys(categoryKeys);

        return dataset;
    }
    private static DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset createDataset3() {
        Number[] dymmy1_Start = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] dummy1_End = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] series2_Start = new Number[] {150,150};
        Number[] series2_End = new Number[] {200,200};
        Number[] dymmy2_Start = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] dummy2_End = new Number[] {null,null};

        Number[][] starts = new Number[][]{dymmy1_Start,series2_Start,dymmy2_Start};
        Number[][] ends = new Number[][] {dummy1_End,series2_End,dummy2_End};
        String[]  categoryKeys = {"50th%ile", "90th%ile"};
        String[] seriesKeys = {"","Series3",""};
        DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset dataset= new DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset(starts, ends);
        dataset.setSeriesKeys(seriesKeys);
        dataset.setCategoryKeys(categoryKeys);

        return dataset;
    }
    private static DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset createDataset4() {
        Number[] dymmy1_Start = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] dummy1_End = new Number[] {null,null};
        Number[] series2_Start = new Number[] {50,50};
        Number[] series2_End = new Number[] {100,100};
        Number[][] starts = new Number[][]{dymmy1_Start,series2_Start};
        Number[][] ends = new Number[][] {dummy1_End,series2_End, };
        String[]  categoryKeys = {"50th%ile", "90th%ile"};
        String[] seriesKeys = {"","Series4"};
        DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset dataset= new DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset(starts, ends);
        dataset.setSeriesKeys(seriesKeys);
        dataset.setCategoryKeys(categoryKeys);

        return dataset;
    }
    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset1, CategoryDataset dataset2, CategoryDataset dataset3,CategoryDataset dataset4) {

        CategoryAxis domainAxis = new CategoryAxis("Percentiles");

        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("ms1");
        IntervalBarRenderer renderer = new IntervalBarRenderer();
        rendererSettings(renderer);
        //CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset1, domainAxis, rangeAxis,renderer);
final CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset1, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer) {

            /**
             * Override the getLegendItems() method to handle special case.
             *
             * @return the legend items.
             */
            public LegendItemCollection getLegendItems() {

                final LegendItemCollection result = new LegendItemCollection();

                final CategoryDataset data = getDataset();
                if (data != null) {
                    final CategoryItemRenderer r = getRenderer();
                    if (r != null) {
                        final LegendItem item = r.getLegendItem(0, 0);
                        result.add(item);
                    }
                }

                // the JDK 1.2.2 compiler complained about the name of this
                // variable 
                final CategoryDataset dset2 = getDataset(1);
                if (dset2 != null) {
                    final CategoryItemRenderer renderer2 = getRenderer(1);
                    if (renderer2 != null) {
                        final LegendItem item = renderer2.getLegendItem(1, 1);
                        result.add(item);
                    }
                }
                final CategoryDataset dset3 = getDataset(2);
                if (dset3 != null) {
                    final CategoryItemRenderer renderer2 = getRenderer(2);
                    if (renderer2 != null) {
                        final LegendItem item = renderer2.getLegendItem(2, 1);
                        result.add(item);
                    }
                }
                final CategoryDataset dset4 = getDataset(3);
                if (dset4 != null) {
                    final CategoryItemRenderer renderer2 = getRenderer(3);
                    if (renderer2 != null) {
                        final LegendItem item = renderer2.getLegendItem(3, 1);
                        result.add(item);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

        };

        ///////////

        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Percentiles", plot);

    //  final CategoryPlot plot2 = chart.getCategoryPlot();      
    //  CategoryAxis axis = plot2.getDomainAxis();      
    //  final CategoryDataset dataset2 = createDataset2();
        plot.setDataset(1, dataset2);
        plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);      
        final ValueAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis("ms2");
        plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);
        IntervalBarRenderer renderer2 = new IntervalBarRenderer();
        rendererSettings(renderer2);
        plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);

        plot.setDataset(2, dataset3);
        plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(2, 2);      
        final ValueAxis axis3 = new NumberAxis("ms3");
        plot.setRangeAxis(2, axis3);
        IntervalBarRenderer renderer3 = new IntervalBarRenderer();
        rendererSettings(renderer3);
        plot.setRenderer(2, renderer3);

        plot.setDataset(3, dataset4);
        plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(3, 3);      
        final ValueAxis axis4 = new NumberAxis("ms4");
        plot.setRangeAxis(3, axis4);
        IntervalBarRenderer renderer4 = new IntervalBarRenderer();
        rendererSettings(renderer4);
        plot.setRenderer(3, renderer4);



        ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);
        return chart;

    }
    private static void rendererSettings(IntervalBarRenderer renderer){
    //  renderer.setItemLabelFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,2));
    //  renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new IntervalCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
    //  renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE6, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));
    //  renderer.setItemMargin(0.3);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);    

    }
    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset1(),createDataset2(),createDataset3(),createDataset4());
        return new ChartPanel(chart);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame demo = new IntervalBarChartTest(
                "Testing");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: May use translucent colors or let the user control visibility, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513).

Comment: Might a [`StackedBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/StackedBarRenderer.html) or [`GroupedStackedBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GroupedStackedBarRenderer.html) be applicable?