# Choose the series of data that you want to display

Tags: java, swing, plot, jfreechart

I have a plot with multiple series of data:

[image]

I want to be able to pick the series that I want to display. For example, only the `0°` and `20°` ones. Is there a simple way to do this by manipulating the chart without using `JCheckBox`? I want to be able to do this, for example, by clicking on the legend of the series.

Comment: Does _label of the series_ mean the chart's _legend_?

Comment: @trashgod yes, sorry it was not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513), `JCheckBox` is more flexible, but clicking directly on the chart may be more convenient. The example below adds a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) that makes a series invisible when clicking on either an [`XYItemEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/XYItemEntity.html) in the series or its [`LegendItemEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/LegendItemEntity.html). Of course, once a series is invisible, it cannot be clicked on again; you'll need a way to restore visibility. Among some alternatives, the first is illustrated below:

- Restore the visibility of all series when clicking elsewhere on the chart.
- Combine this with the approach cited above, toggling the `JCheckBox` accordingly in your implementation of `chartMouseClicked()`.
- Loop through the series in a button handler, restoring the visibility of each.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.ChartEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.LegendItemEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.XYItemEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286042/230513 */
public class VisibleTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("value" + i);
            for (double t = 0; t < 2 * Math.PI; t += 0.5) {
                series.add(t, Math.sin(t) + i);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("domain");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("range");
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true);
        renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Test", plot);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
                ChartEntity ce = e.getEntity();
                if (ce instanceof XYItemEntity) {
                    XYItemEntity item = (XYItemEntity) ce;
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(item.getSeriesIndex(), false);
                } else if (ce instanceof LegendItemEntity) {
                    LegendItemEntity item = (LegendItemEntity) ce;
                    Comparable key = item.getSeriesKey();
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(dataset.getSeriesIndex(key), false);
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
                        renderer.setSeriesVisible(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {}
        });

        f.add(chartPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new VisibleTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code working for you? `getSeriesKey()` and `getSeriesIndex()` are not recognised in these two lines: `Comparable key = item.getSeriesKey();
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(dataset.getSeriesIndex(key), false);`

Comment: Yes; I just checked the posted code with [tag:jfreechart] version 1.0.19.

Comment: My bad, had a problem with my `JFreeChart` version. Thanks for your answer anyway, it was exactly what I was looking for. I think that I'll combine the two solutions in order to have the best user experience!