# JavaFX Use Chart Legend to toggle show/hide Series possible?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, legend

Is it possible to use a chart's legend to toggle show/hide a series?

I got a `LineChart` with a legend and there are too many `Series` so you can't read out the information well. I was wondering if there is a possibility to use the legend to toggle the series to show/hide?

Most of the names of my `Series` are pretty long and it looks very weird if they are written twice once in the legend so you know which color belongs to which `Series` and a second time besides a `CheckBox` to toggle them.

Edit1: Maybe I was unclear, even if there is no built in function for this, I could use some input for how a workaround could look like, because I can't come up with anything.

Comment: There isn't a built-in way as far as I know, but I had a working roundabout solution, I'll see if I can dig it up and post it.

Comment: @sillyfly that would be awesome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I solved this - I am not aware of any simpler built-in solution

```
LineChart<Number, Number> chart;

for (Node n : chart.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
    if (n instanceof Legend) {
        Legend l = (Legend) n;
        for (Legend.LegendItem li : l.getItems()) {
            for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> s : chart.getData()) {
                if (s.getName().equals(li.getText())) {
                    li.getSymbol().setCursor(Cursor.HAND); // Hint user that legend symbol is clickable
                    li.getSymbol().setOnMouseClicked(me -> {
                        if (me.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                            s.getNode().setVisible(!s.getNode().isVisible()); // Toggle visibility of line
                            for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> d : s.getData()) {
                                if (d.getNode() != null) {
                                    d.getNode().setVisible(s.getNode().isVisible()); // Toggle visibility of every node in the series
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to run this code once on your chart (`LineChart` in this example, but you can probably adapt it to any other chart). I find the `Legend` child, and then iterate over all of its' items. I match the legend item to the correct series based on the name - from my experience they always match, and I couldn't find a better way to match them. Then it's just a matter of adding the correct event handler to that specific legend item.

Answer (score 4):

For reference, a similar approach works with [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) in JavaFX as shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117471). Adapted from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286042/230513), the variation below adds a `ChartMouseListenerFX` to the `ChartViewer`. Click on a series or its legend item to make a series invisible; click anywhere else to restore it.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.ChartEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.LegendItemEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.XYItemEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.ChartViewer;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.interaction.ChartMouseEventFX;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.interaction.ChartMouseListenerFX;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967809/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286042/230513
 */
public class VisibleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("value" + i);
            for (double t = 0; t < 2 * Math.PI; t += 0.5) {
                series.add(t, Math.sin(t) + i);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("domain");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("range");
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true);
        renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Test", plot);
        ChartViewer viewer = new ChartViewer(chart);
        viewer.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListenerFX() {
            @Override
            public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEventFX e) {
                ChartEntity ce = e.getEntity();
                if (ce instanceof XYItemEntity) {
                    XYItemEntity item = (XYItemEntity) ce;
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(item.getSeriesIndex(), false);
                } else if (ce instanceof LegendItemEntity) {
                    LegendItemEntity item = (LegendItemEntity) ce;
                    Comparable key = item.getSeriesKey();
                    renderer.setSeriesVisible(dataset.getSeriesIndex(key), false);
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
                        renderer.setSeriesVisible(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEventFX e) {}
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(viewer));
        stage.setTitle("JFreeChartFX");
        stage.setWidth(640);
        stage.setHeight(480);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also an option, thank you, but the first one workst better in conjunction with the rest of my programm.

Comment: @Daniel: I agree; I mostly just wanted to adduce an example of porting an existing `JFreeChart` to JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer @sillyfly. I was able to port this to Kotlin. It comes out cleanly and succinctly with the `forEach` and `filter` notation.

(Kotlin-folk, please let me know any improvements, thanks).

```
        lineChart.childrenUnmodifiable.forEach { if (it is Legend) {
            it.items.forEach {
                val li = it
                lineChart.data.filter { it.name == li.text }.forEach {
                    li.symbol.cursor = Cursor.HAND
                    val s = it
                    li.symbol.setOnMouseClicked { if (it.button == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                        s.node.isVisible = !s.node.isVisible
                        s.data.forEach { it.node.isVisible = !it.node.isVisible }
                    }}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, but too long for a comment and useful if you've made the switch to TornadoFX (which is based on JavaFX). Hiding the series can be achieved behind the scenes by adding the extension

```
fun XYChart<Number, Number>.showExtra(on: Boolean) {

    for (s in getData()) {

        s.getNode().setVisible(on)

        for (d in s.getData()) {

            if (d.getNode() != null) {

                d.getNode().setVisible(on)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works with new versions of JavaFX and with Kotlin. It also solves the problem of import com.sun.javafx.charts package:

```
val items: Set<Node> = lineChart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item")
    items.forEach { label ->
        if(label is Label)
            label.setOnMouseClicked {
                lineChart.data.forEach {
                    if(it.name == label.text) {
                        it.node.isVisible = !it.node.isVisible
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```