# JavaFX multiple linechat align

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a page with multiple charts all aligned by the date/time (i use a numericAxis with a custom label formatting).
As you can see in the image above the charts starting point are not aligned.

Is it possible to dynamicly align the starting point or, at least, specify a fixed side for the left space?

I'm using multiple LineChart contained into a GridPane.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try setting the start point and end point for each graph.

Comment: Maybe a `CombinedDomainXYPlot`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513); JavaFX usage shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967809/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further tests i found

```
yAxis.setMinWidth(50.);
yAxis.setPrefWidth(50.);
yAxis.setMaxWidth(50.);
```

Here the results

[image]