# Formatting tooltip value with StandardXYToolTipGenerator

Tags: java, formatting, tooltip, rounding, jfreechart

In desktop Java project I used `StandardXYToolTipGenerator` for generating tooltips on chart.

Renderer was configured as below:

```
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator("{0} - {2} ({1})",new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"), NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));
```

Where `{2}` is value (example 1.149431) but when I am using `NumberFormat` it format itself and return value 1.149, I want get precisely rounding. How to get it? Any idea?

I tried extend `NumberFormat` class, but method `format(double number)` is final...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance--) "Returns a general-purpose number format for the current default `FORMAT` locale." You can adjust the rounding mode and the number of digits as desired. Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286042/230513), the fragment below retains the default rounding mode and specifies five digits.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(5);
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(
    "{2}", DateFormat.getDateInstance(), format));
```

[image]

As an aside, verify that your chosen `SimpleDateFormat` is appropriate for for your target locale.

Comment: That is it! Thanks ;)