# java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: f

Tags: java, histogram

I am trying to get histogram of an image using this code [Displaying a histogram of image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519355/displaying-a-histogram-of-image-data). Normally it works fine when input image given by url. But while I give image from local directory

```
private BufferedImage getImage() {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new URL(
            "F:/test.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

it gives exception,

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: f
```

How to resolve this exception and get Histogram of an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers will technically solve your problem, you shouldn't be using a `URL` for this. There are other signatures for the `read` function, [one which takes a `File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) and one [which takes an `InputStream` instead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-), so you can use either of the following:

```
return ImageIO.read(new File("F:/test.jpg"));
// or
return ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("F:/test.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`F:/test.jpg` is not a valid URL. For files the URL is `file://F:/test.jpg`
where `file` is the protocol

Answer (score 1):

The protocol is not valid.

If you need to load a file from the filesystem you need to use the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

> A file URI takes the form of `file://host/path`
>
> where `host` is the fully qualified domain name of the system on which the path is accessible, and path is a hierarchical directory path of the form `directory/directory/.../name`. If `host` is omitted, it is taken to be "`localhost`", the machine from which the URL is being interpreted.

So the url should be:

```
file://F:/test.jpg
```