# JFreeChart not plotting sequentially

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm facing one problem while plotting JFreeChart. I have 5 series(lines) to plot on a graph. In those 5 series, 1 series has a different x coordinates (In the graph you can check in end 74 is there for p25.). This creates problems. How can fix it so as not to show 74 in the last? instead show it after 72 in ascending order.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxfjX.png]]

Comment: What problems? It’s going to plot the data you give it—if you don’t want it to plot something don’t tell it to?

Comment: Consider leveraging the _pan_ and _zoom_ features examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20pan%20zoom&searchOn=3), or toggle series visibility, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513).

Comment: @DaveNewton  my problem was solved after using XYSeriesCollection